# Can i use multiple prop() for different fields in Jquery..?

Tags: jquery, prop

I have the below code which will reset the fields.

```
$('#email').find('input,textarea').val('');
$('#email').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);            
$('#email').find('select option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
```

My question is, can i make the above code to similar to below one. Does it valid..?

```
$('#email').find('input,textarea,input[type=checkbox],select option:eq(0)').val('').prop('checked', false).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Not really, as `input` and `textarea` don't have `checked` or `selected` properties. However, assuming this is the initial state of the form your could just do `$('form')[0].reset();`

Comment: #hat is this `$('#email')` is it a div or a form element ?

Comment: It's a modal id @SamuelJMathew

Comment: do you have any form in modal if so you can reset it `$('form')[0].reset();`

Comment: valid - yes, but would you want to maintain it ?

Comment: I dont have the form in that modal @SamuelJMathew

Comment: Yes. I have to maintain it, because i am using that single modal for dynamic fields @Stavm

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can do that.
As the result, you will have a textarea with `checked` and `selected` properties.

Yes, it will work.
Yes, it *shouldn't* have any undesired effect.
However, it doesn't sound good.

Moreover, your second approach does definitely not improve code readability.

```js
function display(propName) {
  console.log("checkbox." + propName + " = " + $("#checkbox").prop(propName));
  console.log("text." + propName + " = " + $("#text").prop(propName));
  console.log("textarea." + propName + " = " + $("#textarea").prop(propName));
}

display("checked");

$("input, textarea").prop("checked", true);

display("checked");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my experiments here i came to a conclusion that you can reset form element using below code inside a div :-

```js
function reset() {
  $(':input', '#email')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .each(function(i, e) {
      $(e).val($(e).attr('value') || '')
        .prop('checked', false)
        .prop('selected', false)
    })

  $('option[selected]', this).prop('selected', true)
  $('input[checked]', this).prop('checked', true)
  $('textarea', this).each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).val($(e).html())
  })

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="email">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
  <input type="text" id="text" />
  <textarea></textarea>
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option value="TRUE">TRUE</option>
  </select>
  <buttion onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```